# Raspberry Pi 2 - bare metal DMA

Tags: c, bare-metal

I am trying to make DMA on bare-metal raspberry Pi2 working. Unfortunatelly it does not and I have got no idea why. Below is my source code:

```
typedef struct{
    UINT32 controlStatus;
    UINT32 controlBlockAddr;
    UINT32 transferInformation;
    UINT32 sourceAddr;
    UINT32 destAddr;
    UINT32 transferLength;
    UINT32 stride;
    UINT32 nextControlBlock;
    UINT32 debug;
}DMA_Channel;

typedef struct{
    UINT32 transferInformation;
    UINT32 sourceAddr;
    UINT32 destAddr;
    UINT32 transferLength;
    UINT32 stride;
    UINT32 nextControlBlock;
    UINT32 dummy0;
    UINT32 dummy1;
} DMA_ControlBlock __attribute__ ((aligned(32)));

#define PERIPH_BASE (0x3F000000)
#define DMA_OFFSET  (0x00007000)
#define DMA_DIFF    (0x00000100)
#define DMA_CHAN_0  (*((volatile DMA_Channel*)(PERIPH_BASE + DMA_OFFSET)))
#define DMA_ENABLE  (*((volatile UINT32*)(PERIPH_BASE+DMA_OFFSET+0xff0)))
#define DMA_INT_REG (*((volatile UINT32*)(PERIPH_BASE+DMA_OFFSET+0xfe0)))

DMA_ControlBlock dma_controlBlock;

void testDMA(){
    DMA_INT_REG = 0;
    DMA_ENABLE |= 1<<0;

    unsigned long source[100] = {0x00FF00FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0x00FF00FF, 0x00FF00FF};
    unsigned long dest[100] = {0,0,0,0, 0};

    DMA_CHAN_0.controlStatus |= 1<<31; // reset
    DMA_CHAN_0.controlStatus |= 1<<1;

    dma_controlBlock.transferInformation = 0;
    dma_controlBlock.transferInformation |= 1<<26; // no wide bursts
    dma_controlBlock.transferInformation |= 1<<8; //src incerement
    dma_controlBlock.transferInformation |= 1<<4; //dst increment
    dma_controlBlock.sourceAddr = (UINT32)(&source) | 0xC0000000;
    dma_controlBlock.destAddr = (UINT32)(&dest)| 0xC0000000;
    dma_controlBlock.nextControlBlock =0;
    dma_controlBlock.stride = 0;
    dma_controlBlock.transferLength = 100;
    dma_controlBlock.dummy0 =0;
    dma_controlBlock.dummy1 =0;

    DMA_CHAN_0.controlStatus |= 1<<29; // disdebug
    DMA_CHAN_0.controlBlockAddr = ((UINT32)&dma_controlBlock) | 0xC0000000;
    DMA_CHAN_0.controlStatus |= 1; //start

    while(DMA_CHAN_0.controlStatus & 1<<0){
        hexstring(DMA_CHAN_0.debug);
        hexstring(DMA_CHAN_0.sourceAddr);
    }

    if(dest[2] == source[2]){
        hexstring(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    else
        hexstring(0xAAAAAAAA);

    DMA_CHAN_0.controlStatus |= 1<<1;
    while(1);
}
```

I know it's not a debug site, but I have no idea where the demon hides.
I am giving it a proper addresses (addr | 0xC0000000 ). but it does not. work. It does not even says, that DMA is working, so `while(DMA_CHAN_0.controlStatus & 1<<0)` is never true, as if it has never been launched.

Here in this example all I want to do is copy one block of memory to another.
To check if it's completed I do a dummy test, where I check if an element in destination array is same as in the source array one. hexstring() method is method, that prints on uart, value given in a hex. That's how I know, that it is not working well.

I set sizes of arrays for 100, so that to be sure, that immediately after launching it DMA will still be copying, so that I can test if Active bit is set and print some messages via UART. hexstring() function is function borrowed from dwelch67.

Comment: Have you tried the Bare Metal forum at raspberrypi.org?  All my experience is from Linux userland where or'ing with 0xC000000 is not sufficient to get a DMA coherent memory address on a Pi2/Pi3.

Comment: Hi, it's not enough on userland on Linux that's true, because then you reside in virtual memory, that is mapped by your OS. When programming with no OS (as in my example) or at least with MMU disabled you reside in physical memory and from this you can directly map to BUS memory. I already asked this question : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=148017

Comment: Are you only executing one block?  That will be over before you can test the flag.  Don't you want to loop so doesn't nextControlBlock need to point to itself or another control block?

Comment: I will do some edit to explain, what I want to do. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @joan But generally yes, I want to copy only one block. and I am testing arbitrary element in destination array if it matches the same element number in source array. I print on uart appropriate value if it fails.

Comment: I haven't spotted anything obviously wrong.  I don't remember having to write to addresses DMA base + 0xff0/0xfe0 from userland.

Comment: @joan interrupt register is set up on 0 on boot, so I did this only for sanity. That's also possible, that Linux by default enables all DMA channels, so you did not have to enable dmas manually. Either way, thanks for interest. I'm really grateful